# Listbox in tk/tcl

Tags: listbox, tcl, tk-toolkit

Help me please to decide problem with listbox in TCL.
I created the next listbox:

```
listbox .lb1 -height 6 -width 10 -selectmode browse
.lb1 insert 0 "String 1" "String 2" "String 3" "String 4" "String 5" "String  6"

label .label1 -text [.lb1 get active]
button .butt1 -text "enter" -command {.label1 configure -text [.lb1 get active]}
pack .label1 .lb1 .butt1 -expand yes -fill both
```

How I can change automatically contents of label "label1" without use button "butt1" ?

I want the contents of "label1" will change immediately when I click on one of the list items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select an item in the listbox, it sends the `<<ListboxSelect>>` to itself. You can bind to this to react to selection changes:

```
bind .lb1 <<ListboxSelect>> {.label1 configure -text [.lb1 get active]}
```

Note that you're also getting very close to the point where using a helper procedure is advised. Even for something simple like this, it makes things easier to write, test and debug.

```
proc SelectionHappened {listbox label} {
    set activeItem [$listbox get active]
    $label configure -text $activeItem
}
bind .lb1 <<ListboxSelect>> {SelectionHappened .lb1 .label1}
```